# Run Chrome Extensions using command prompt

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to run a chrome extension from command line?
I need to automate the process for my software, and my software will need to run that extension with a particular parameter.

I am using a Chrome Extension 'APK Downloader' by Yogi. The Extension works like this:-
    "If a page contains any *.apk* file link, then when I **click** on the extension's icon on the address bar, it starts direct download of that *.apk* file"

Now, I have my software that needs some *.apk* file to download [The software will have the package name of the *.apk* file to be downloaded, which is used by the extension to generate a download link]. It will be an automatic process. So, I need to know if it is possible to pass a parameter to the extension automatically, and make the extension to work without clicking on it.

Is it possible to do so??

Answer (score 17):

Unpacked extension can be loaded using the `--load-extension=` flag.

What I usually do is `chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/someuniquedirname --load-extension=path/to/extension --no-first-run`.

- The `--user-data-dir=` flag is used to specify a non-default [user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), to minimize conflicts between your existing browser profile and the test directory. You can omit this flag if you want to use your default user profile.
- The `--no-first-run`flag prevents the first run UI from showing up (e.g. the bubble that explains how to use the omnibox, and a "Getting Started" page that opens in a new tab).

You can load multiple extensions by separating the paths by commas, e.g. `chromium --load-extension=path/to/one/extension,path/to/another/extension`.

I have published some shell scripts and a convenience extension to speed up (manual) testing of Chrome extensions. Take a look at https://github.com/Rob--W/extension-dev-tools/tree/master/chrome.

Comment: Sir, I need to know if it is possible to execute the chrome extension using command prompt!

Comment: @Vivek Only if the extension supports it. E.g. if it offers its functionality through a file called `examplepage.html`, then open Chrome using e.g. `chrome.exe chrome-extension://[EXTENSION ID HERE]/examplepage.html?parameter=http://example.com/app.apk`.

Comment: @RobW, Btw, is there any way to stop the annoying `about:welcome` screen from appearing?

Comment: @Pacerier Just pass some URL to Chrome, e.g. `about:blank` . Add `--no-first-run` if you don't want to see the welcome bubble either.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1588639/660666 .

Answer (score 1):

it helps to open extension normally and after that hit F12 (dev tools) to see actual url...
having that i can, for example load "Selenium IDE" chrome extension as
(run from command prompt)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\new_chrome.exe" chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

on a mac:

```
osascript <<EOD
set theURL to "chrome://extensions/"
tell application "Google Chrome"
 if windows = {} then
  make new window
  set URL of (active tab of window 1) to theURL
 else
  make new tab at the end of window 1 with properties {URL:theURL}
 end if
 activate
end tell
EOD
```

Question answered here:
https://superuser.com/a/979678