# Chromium won't launch extensions when started from command line

Tags: google-chrome-extension, raspberry-pi, chromium

Having a weird issue with Chromium on a Raspberry Pi. I am trying to get the  Chrome extension "Revolver" to auto start when I load up Chromium. I want it to cycle through each of my tabs right when I launch Chromium.

This works totally fine when I physically click on the Chromium icon, it launches Chromium and then the "Revolver" extension starts working and cycles through my tabs.

However, when I launch Chromium through the Raspberry Pi's autostart file like this:

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --enable-extension-apps --enable-extensions --enable-apps
```

It launches chrome, but the "Revolver" extension does not auto start. It will only work if I then click on the extension icon. I am not sure why it DOES auto start when I manually launch Chromium, but DOES NOT auto start when launching through the autostart file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193369/run-chrome-extensions-using-command-prompt

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?