# How to add extension to running remote multilogin webdriver? (Selenium C#)

Tags: c#, selenium

First I tried to add extension directly from chrome webstore, but problem is alert popup which appears after you click "add to chrome" is not reachable by selenium. After I wanted to try using `options.AddExtension`, but multilogin profile starts before selenium takes control so this method is useless. I know that I can manually import `.crx` for every profile but there are thousands of profiles and I need to automate process of installing extensions. I don't know what to do, I heared there's option to reach popup alert in chrome webstore but can't find it. Or maybe there are other ways to install extension after browser started? I'm glad for any help or advice

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 possible scenarios for you, hope that works out since I don't have direct access to this specific need you have because the extensions may differ.

1. Not using Selenium, you gonna start the chrome process using the class `Process` and add the flag `--load-extension=` to load the specific profile/extension that you need. You can see the entire comma [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193369/run-chrome-extensions-using-command-prompt). To sum, you can use this snippet below to load:

   chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/someuniquedirname --load-extension=path/to/extension --no-first-run //Note: some flags may change between versions of chrome, see full documentation

After defining the extension and start chrome, you can now get hold of the process with Selenium by using another flag: `--remote-debugging-port=http://localhost:[localporthere]`. After that, start the process than tell to Selenium to get hold of that process with the port and do your job.

2. Another way is to start the process installing the extension manually and in another Thread use some Automation UI (Teststack.White or FlaUI) to click on the popup you have. I can't extend here in the entire code for this solution because it will go to a opinion-based answer, but you can check on FlaUI for that use, and follow that path:

1. Selenium starts the program, click on the install extension and wait for the popup to show-up;
2. New Thread;
3. FlaUI gets hold of the process that you already start;
4. Using UIElements, click on the "ok" button you need;
5. FlaUI drops;
6. Back to the main thread.

If you need any clarifications about the solutions above, just comment and I'll try to help you further.